# Optimizing a linq query for collecting matching objects from two lists

Tags: c#, .net, performance, linq

I have two lists of objects (list 1 and list 2) and I need to create a third list of objects from list 1 that share a property value with at least one object from list 2. I created the following linq query to do this, however, it is quite slow (in large part, no doubt, because the two starting lists can contain up to 200,000 objects).

```
(from obj1 in _list1
 from obj2 in _list2
 where obj1.SpecialId == obj2.SpecialId
 select obj1)
.ToList();
```

Is there a more efficient way to implement this in code (perhaps without using linq in the first place)?

Comment: Make a `HashSet<int>` (assuming `SpecialId` is `int`). loop over `_list2` and add each `SpecialId` to the hashset. Then your result is `_list1.Where(l => !hashSet.Contains(l.SpecialId));`

Comment: SpecialId is a long. Would your suggestion still work?

Comment: @fyodorfranz Yes, but you'd need to change the hashset to `HashSet<long>`

Comment: @Rob That's awesome! I've implemented your suggestion and an operation that once took 29 seconds now, somehow, takes 2 seconds. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @fyodorfranz No worries, mate :)

Answer (score 5):

You can use LINQ `Join` to do this.

Query syntax:

```
var result = (from obj1 in _list1
            join obj2 in _list2 on obj1.SpecialId equals obj2.SpecialId
            select obj1
            ).ToList();
```

Method syntax:

```
var result = _list1.Join(_list2, obj1 => obj1.Id, obj2 => obj2.Id, (obj1, obj2) => obj1).ToList();
```

According to my simple tests, version with `Join` is about 5-6 times faster than Your original version.